# Prevent incomplete file transfer over FTP using WinSCP .NET Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am simply trying to transfer text files from one **FTP** server to another using a **windows service**. I download the required files from source FTP server and save it locally on my system and then upload the saved file to the destination server. For downloading and uploading files I am using **WinSCP .Net Assembly**. Here is my code that I am using to transfer files to the destination server:

```
WinSCP.SessionOptions sessionOptions = new WinSCP.SessionOptions();
sessionOptions.Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Ftp;
sessionOptions.UserName = "myUsername";
sessionOptions.Password = "myPassword"
sessionOptions.PortNumber = 21;
sessionOptions.HostName = serverIPAddress;

session.Open(sessionOptions);

WinSCP.TransferOptions transferOptions = new WinSCP.TransferOptions();
transferOptions.TransferMode = WinSCP.TransferMode.Binary;
WinSCP.TransferOperationResult transferResult;
transferResult = session.PutFiles(PathToLocalFile + filename, destinationFilePath, false, transferOptions);
transferResult.Check();
```

It works fine and uploads file to the server, but in case a connectivity issue occurs while transferring the file, an incomplete chunk of required file is transferred to the destination server.

I have searched the WinSCP official documentation but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Is there any way to ensure that only complete files gets transferred to the destination otherwise (in case an error occurs during transfer), the transferred chunk of file gets deleted automatically? (Without manually deleting the incomplete file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no way to make this automatic.

You have to code it. Just check, if the transfer failed, reconnect (if needed), and delete the partially uploaded file.

Though as already mentioned in comments, if the transfer fails, because of problems with connection, you may not be able to reconnect to delete the file.

There's no magic solution. The server should be able to deal with partial files in the first place.

See also:

- [How to detect that a file is being uploaded over FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29238153/850848) (while seemingly different topic, detecting if file is *being uploaded* is basically the same thing, as detecting if file has not been *uploaded completely*)
- [File upload with WinSCP .NET/COM with temporary filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27041606/850848)