# Does WinSCP Session.GetFiles check if file is finished uploading?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using WinSCP .NET assembly library to perform some SFTP operations - downloading files from SFTP location.

Do you know if method `Session.GetFiles` of the WinSCP library checks if file is not corrupted before downloading it - I mean the situation when someone uploads file to given folder and in the same time the WinSCP library wants to get files from this location?

Comment: How would it check if its corrupted, its just a binary file to it.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. There's generally no way to test, if a file is being written to, over an SFTP protocol.

---

File locking is supported by few SFTP servers only. Notably it is not supported by the most widespread SFTP server, the OpenSSH.

See also:

- [SFTP file lock mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26932341/850848);
- WinSCP article on [Locking files while uploading](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_locking_files_while_uploading).

Comment: What if I try to rename file before downloading and if I cant then it means that it is  uploading?

Comment: On a typical *nix system you can rename a file while it is being written to.