# SFTP Downloading While Uploading

Tags: ssis, sftp

The link below is a very similar question to this but I am wondering if things have changed in a couple of years / what's actually happening with my situation.

As a test, I upload a 425MB file to a 3rd party vendor's SFTP server (which can be seen immediately on the server) and I have an SSIS package start downloading that file right away. The process takes about 20 minutes but at the end I have downloaded a full file that looks exactly the same as the uploaded file.

Is it possible the SFTP server can "handle" this and I can trust this to work properly (no partial reads or anything) if it were to happen in production or do I still need to do workarounds suggested in the link below?

Knowing nothing about SFTP servers I would think some sort of SFTP software would manage this for you without needing workarounds..

[SFTP file uploading and downloading at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848774/sftp-file-uploading-and-downloading-at-same-time)

Thank you!

Comment: This is terribly broad question. As my answer to the linked question already says, this all about the SFTP server. We do not know anything at all about your SFTP server. -- And in general, nothing has changed since I've posted that answer (after all, the last time I've updated it was only 6 months ago).

Comment: your post is a solution to a problem. If you read my post, I don't have a problem. The process seems to work fine. So my question is if it's working, why do I need a workaround? I would like someone that knows a lot about SFTPs to explain to me why it's working for me, and if I need to be concerned about it not working sometimes.

Comment: To clarify, it's been difficult to get any sort of information from the 3rd party on the configuration of the SFTP server. So I am wondering if SFTP servers do exist that can handle the scenario? and that's why it works for me?

Comment: 1) Then you do not have a programming question, so it's not in the scope of this site. 2) There are zillions of reasons why it can work for you. Unless you restrict the scope of your question, we can hardly help you, even if you had a programming question. You at least know version string of the SFTP server, if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are attempting to avoid a potential race condition. A simple solution to this is to upload the file to an Uploading directory. Once the file transfer is complete, move the file to a Source or Archive folder (name it whatever you want). Then build all download processes to only look in the Source or Archive folder.