# PSFTP rename file after transfer completed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sftp, psftp

I am transferring files through PSFTP to 3rd party server using Batch files. While transferring files, due to buffering issues, files are being broken/not transferred fully.

As a remedy, 3rd party requested us to name each file with '.new' before starting file transfer and remove '.new' once file is transferred fully/successfully.

Please let me know Batch script commands to implement above. Please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: `psftp` has a `ren` command to rename a file on a remote computer. At the `psftp` prompt type `help` and press `Enter`. The `ren` would be placed into the ftp script used to transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file, use [`mv` command](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mv) (or it's `ren` alias):

```
put c:\local\path\file /remote/path/file.new
mv /remote/path/file.new /remote/path/file
```

Though if you are transferring multiple files using a wildcard, this won't help you.

A relatively simple solution for multiple files is using a temporary upload folder. After the upload finishes, you can move all files at once to the target folder:

```
mput c:\local\path\* /temp/path
mv /temp/path/* /remote/path
```

For a similar discussion, see also [SFTP file lock mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26932341/850848).

---

If you need to use the solution with extensions, you can use WinSCP, as it allows you to automatically use a temporary file name for upload. Though it uses `.filepart`, not `.new` extension.

```
put -resumesupport=on c:\local\path\* /remote/path/
```

See WinSCP article on [Uploading to temporary file name](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_locking_files_while_uploading) for more details.

The article also shows (a way more complicated) [solution using WinSCP .NET assembly that allows you to use even the `.new` extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_locking_files_while_uploading#rename).

If you choose to switch to WinSCP, there's a [guide for converting psftp script to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*