# Can pscp transfer to a temporary file and rename once done?

Tags: sftp, scp, pscp

I have a very big file that has to be transferred to a remote server.

On that remote server there is a job activating *each 5 min* that, once  sees a file name starting with the right prefix, processes it.

What happens if the job "wakes up" in the middle of transfer? In that case it would process a corrupted file.

Do pscp create a .temp file and renames it accordingly to account for that? Or do I have to handle this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `pscp` does not transfer the files via a temporary file.

You would have to use another SFTP client – If you use `pscp` as SFTP client. The `pscp` defaults to SFTP, but it falls back to SCP, if SFTP is not available. If you need to use SCP (what is rare), you cannot do this, as SCP protocol does not support file rename.

---

Either an SFTP client that at least supports file rename – Upload explicitly to a temporary file name and rename afterwards. For that you can use [`psftp`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) from PuTTY package, with its [`put`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-put) and [`mv` commands](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mv):

```
open user@hostname
put C:\source\path\file.zip /destination/path/file.tmp
mv /destination/path/file.tmp /destination/path/file.zip
exit
```

---

Or use an SFTP client that can upload a files via a temporary file automatically. For example [WinSCP](https://winscp.net) can do that. By default it does for files over 100 KB only. If your files are smaller, you can configure it to do it for all files using the [`-resumesupport` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#resumesupport).

An example batch file that forces an upload of a file via a temporary file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 255 ...=""" ^
    "put -resumesupport=on C:\source\path\file.zip /destination/path/" ^
    "exit"
```

The code was [generated by WinSCP GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) with the [*"Transfer to temporary filename"* options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_resume) set to *"All files"*.

See also WinSCP article [Locking files while uploading / Upload to temporary file name](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_locking_files_while_uploading).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Related question: [SFTP file lock mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26932341/850848).